# contents of a list after filter

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

would you please let me how can I print out the contents of persons?

the output of the code is

```
 [Person@72ea2f77, Person@33c7353a, Person@681a9515, Person@3af49f1c,   
 Person@19469ea2]
```

**code**:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val person1 = Person("xyz1", 10);
val person2 = Person("xyz2", 20);
val person3 = Person("xyz3", 30);
val person4 = Person("xyz4", 40);
val person5 = Person("xyz5", 50);

var persons = listOf(
person1, person2, person3, person4 , person5)
.asSequence()
.filter { x-> x.age >=30 }

println(persons.toList())

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either implement `toString()` method in the `Person` class or you can make `Person` class a `data class`.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to show the contents of the Person class is to override the toString method in the Persons class. Here is a working example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val person1 = Person("xyz1", 10);
    val person2 = Person("xyz2", 20);
    val person3 = Person("xyz3", 30);
    val person4 = Person("xyz4", 40);
    val person5 = Person("xyz5", 50);

    var persons = listOf(
            person1, person2, person3, person4, person5)
            .asSequence()
            .filter { x -> x.age >= 30 }

    println(persons.toList())

}

class Person constructor(val name: String, val age: Int) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$name is $age years old."
    }
}
```

**Will output:**

> [xyz3 is 30 years old., xyz4 is 40 years old., xyz5 is 50 years old.]